# How to implement a pseudocode of several stages into LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I have the following question... I have a pseudocode I want to implement in LaTeX
I think the algorithm and algorithmic packages giving quite nice results so I tried it with this one(copied from the manual)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}                      % enter the algorithm environment
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}          % give the algorithm a caption
\label{alg1}                           % and a label for \ref{} commands later in the document
\begin{algorithmic}                    % enter the algorithmic environment
    \REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
    \ENSURE $y = x^n$
    \STATE $y \Leftarrow 1$
    \IF{$n < 0$}
        \STATE $X \Leftarrow 1 / x$
        \STATE $N \Leftarrow -n$
    \ELSE
        \STATE $X \Leftarrow x$
        \STATE $N \Leftarrow n$
    \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

And the result looks also kind of nice to me, see this: 
http://docdro.id/BXSUaWk

But I want the pseudocodes in several stages so it should look more like that:[image: how it should look like]

So I don't want there to be written Algorithm in the beginning but some text I can set (in my case 'Teil') and I want to have several stages just seperated by one black line...

Of course it can also look a little different and of course there is no need at all to use those packages I am using right now...

So can anyone help me? Maybe because he did something like this or something similar already?

I would be very very glad... Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a question probably better suited for tex.stackexchange, but anyway, here goes.

We base our fix of the `algpseudocode` environment `algorithmic` very much on the following thread (specifically Werner´s answer)

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216138/breaking-up-an-algorithm-into-several-parts

We can tweak the `phase` command from the thread above (which really are just a collection of (somewhat advanced) `\Statex` commands -- where the latter is an `algorithmic` environment `\State` command without line number = no indentation) and create the following example for you to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty} % remove default caption

\makeatletter

\newcounter{phase}[algorithm]
\newlength{\phaserulewidth}
\newcommand{\phaseTitle}{Teil} % <-- Enter default "phase name" here
\newcommand{\setphaserulewidth}{\setlength{\phaserulewidth}}

%% Top phase item
\newcommand{\topPhase}[1]{%
  \vspace{2.0ex}
  % Top phase rule = default algorithm rule, leave out for top item
  \Statex\strut\refstepcounter{phase}\item[\textbf{\phaseTitle~\thephase:~}\textit{~#1}] % phase "caption"
  % Bottom phase rule
   \vspace{-3.0ex}\Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}}

%% Rest phase items  
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{%
  \vspace{-1.25ex}
  % Top phase rule
  \Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}
  \Statex\strut\refstepcounter{phase}\item[\textbf{\phaseTitle~\thephase:~}\textit{~#1}] % phase "caption"
  % Bottom phase rule
  \vspace{-1.25ex}\Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}}

\makeatother

\setphaserulewidth{.7pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[0]
       % Top phase
        \topPhase{Calculate $y = x^n$}
        \Require{$n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$} 
        \Ensure{$y = x^n$}
        \State{$y \Leftarrow 1$}
         \If{$n < 0$}
             \State{$X \Leftarrow 1 / x$}
             \State{$N \Leftarrow -n$}
        \Else
            \State{$X \Leftarrow x$}
            \State{$N \Leftarrow n$}
        \EndIf
    % next phase
    \phase{Calculate $z = x^n$}
        \Require{$n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$} 
        \Ensure{$y = x^n$}
        \State{$y \Leftarrow 1$}
        \State{$\dots$}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result of this looks as follows:

[image]

You can customise this further by looking into and adjusting the definitions of the new commands `\topPhase` and `\phase`.